# Prove that a limit of Lebesgue integrable functions tends to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n \in L^+ \cap L^1(m)$, real-valued.

Suppose that $\int_{[0,1/n]} f_n \,dx \geq 1/2$ for each $n$.

Let $g_n(x) = \max_{1\leq j\leq n} f_j(x)$.  Then $g_n \rightarrow g \equiv \sup_n f_n$.

Show that $\int_{[0,1]} g \,dx = \infty$.

My solution.

The monotone convergence theorem gives the existence of some $\epsilon_1>0$ such that $\int_{[\epsilon_1,1]} g_1 \geq 1/3$. Now choose $n_2$ such that $1/n_2 < \epsilon_1$ and choose an $\epsilon_2$ such that $\int_[\epsilon_2,1/2] g_{n_2} \geq 1/3$. In general choose an $n_m$ such that $1/n_m < \epsilon_{m-1}$.  Then choose an $\epsilon_m>0$ such that $\int_{[\epsilon_m,1/n_m]} g_{n_m} \geq 1/3$.

Thus we have identified a sequence of disjoint intervals $U \equiv \cup_m \{(\epsilon_m,1/{n_m})\}_m \subset [0,1]$ such that $\int_U g \geq m/3$. This proves the claim, as $m$ is arbitrary.

Any other solutions. Perhaps something more slick?

Comment: What is $L^+$? ${}{}$

Comment: The space of nonnegative measurable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is integrable, then $\nu A = \int_A g$ is a finite measure and $\nu \ll m$. In particular, if $A_n$ satisfies $mA_n \to 0$, then $\nu A_n \to 0$.

We have $\nu [0,{1 \over n}] = \int_{[0,{1 \over n}]} g \ge \int_{[0,{1 \over n}]} f_n \ge {1 \over 2}$, and clearly $m [0,{1 \over n}] = {1 \over n} \to 0$, hence a contradiction.